# The conjecture: $\binom{2n-1}{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n^3} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad n \in \mathbb{P}$

Tags: conjectures, primality-test

I recall seeing the following conjecture somewhere, but I cannot find the reference any more. Where can I find more information about this conjecture? Does it have a name?

**Conjecture:** For any natural number $n$ it holds that
$$
\binom{2n-1}{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n^3} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad n \in \mathbb{P},
$$
where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem).

For a prime $p > 3$ we have:

$$\binom{2p-1}{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^3}$$

Comment: Although the conjecture in my question has the implication in the opposite direction, I believe this answers my question well enough.

Comment: If you searched in <a href="http://oeis.org">OEIS</a> for the sequence $a_n = \binom{2n-1}{n-1}\mod n^3$ it is <a href="http://oeis.org/A099907">A099907</a> where the first comment is "For p prime > 3, Joseph Wolstenholme showed in 1862 that a(p)=1." Sadly, there is no reference currently in the sequence entry.